# Populate ListView from SQL using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sql, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to populate a ListView with data retrieved from an SQLite Database using a SimpleCursorAdapter. The KEYs that we used for the table are;

_ROWID - for the row number (which should not be visible in the ListView)

_NAME - for the name of a food product in our database (like Bread or Cheese)

_AMOUNT - for the quantity you have of this food product

_DATE - for the expiry date of the product

Another groupmember wrote the code for the database and about halfway through there is a public String called getData. The code looks like this;

```
public class DatabaseCustom {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "expiration_date";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_DATE};

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "customDb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "customTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE
                + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DatabaseCustom(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public DatabaseCustom open() {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name, String amount, String date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
    cv.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT,
            KEY_DATE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT);
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
                + " " + c.getString(iAmount) + " " + c.getString(iDate)
                + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public String getName(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT,
            KEY_DATE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getAmount(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT,
            KEY_DATE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(2);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDate(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT,
            KEY_DATE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(3);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}

public void updateEntry(long lRow, String mName, String mAmount,
        String mDate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mName);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_AMOUNT, mAmount);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_DATE, mDate);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow,
            null);
}

public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);
}
```

From what I gathered I need to set up a populateListView method using a SimpleCursorAdapter in the code for the Activity that shows this ListView. This is the code I have so far (leaving out some code that is irrelevant for my question);

```
public class Products extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

DatabaseCustom ourDb;
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.products);

    openDb();
    initiate();
    populateListView();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        //A few different buttons for this activity here
    }   
}

private void initiate(){
    //Link all the java variables to the corresponding xml elements here
}

private void openDb(){
    ourDb = new DatabaseCustom(this);
    ourDb.open();
}

private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = ourDb.getData();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DatabaseCustom.KEY_NAME, DatabaseCustom.KEY_AMOUNT, DatabaseCustom.KEY_DATE};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.tvProductNameList, R.id.tvAmountList, R.id.tvDateList};
    SimpleCursorAdapter ourCursorAdapter;
    ourCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);//Put text from KEYS into TVs
    ListView ourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);
    ourList.setAdapter(ourCursorAdapter);           
}
```

In the populateListView method I try to create a cursor that looks for the getData method in our database and logicly gives an error as the getData method in this database is a public String and not a public cursor, so I tried to create a public Cursor instead, which I coded as follows;

```
public Cursor getData() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

After adding the codes for private void populateListView and the public Cursor get Data Eclipse doesn't show any errors, but the application crashes when the activity is loaded that is supposed to show the ListView.

After following numerous tutorials on SQL Databases, ListViews, CursorAdapters and String Arrays, I've come to the point where I'm not sure where to look for answers anymore, so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: A good place to start is with the stack trace in your logcat.

Comment: After hours of trying out everything I could find based on our logcat I finally found out we gave two tables from two different databases the same name. Issue was finally resolved after incrementing the database version. Thanks for the tip ;)